# WPF - Get current cell details

Tags: wpf, grid

I have a grid which contains 2 rows and 2 columns. Each cell hosting a windows forms host control. I want to capture the selected cell when the user clicks on any of the cell. I have searched and found that there is no 'Click' event but I can make use of 'MouseDown' event with similar results. But now I am stuck because you would think there must be an easier way like 'GetCurentRow' and 'GetCurrentColumn' to capture the selected cell but there isn't.

What I want further to do is to get the child element in that particular cell of the grid.
I tried the following code but no matter which cell I click, I always get 0 for the row and column:

```
void InnerGridToContainWindowsFormsHost_MouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var element = (UIElement)e.Source;
    int c = Grid.GetColumn(element);
    int r = Grid.GetRow(element);
}
```

Is there any way to get the selected/clicked cell details or the children inside the cell?

Comment: `Each cell hosting a windows forms host control` - What does your winforms contain?

Comment: Each cell contains a WindowsFormHost object which in turn 'hosts' an ActiveX control. My WPF form contains a main grid, its children and one of the children is another grid containing the 4 WindowsFormHost objects.

Comment: An empty `Grid` cell is just that... empty. If you were to put a `Rectangle` with its `Fill` property set in each cell and then clicked in the cells, you would see that `Grid.GetColumn` and `Grid.GetRow` do work as expected. I'm not sure why your `WindowsFormHost` objects are not doing the same job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you may be going down the wrong route here... if you just want to know what control was clicked on, try using the `VisualTreeHelper.HitTest` method. You can find information on the [VisualTreeHelper.HitTest Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.hittest.aspx) page on MSDN. Basically, you would do something like:

```
private void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    // Get the position of the mouse pointer relative to the grid
    Point clickPoint = e.GetPosition(grid);
    HitTestResult result = VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(grid, clickPoint);
    if (result != null) 
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

You may also need some kind of basic recursive function to drill down through the `Visual` objects until you get to the one you want.

Comment: I already know the control inside the grid. What I wanted when the user clicks on the grid was 2 things: 1) Get the current cell(row and column) and change its borderbrush to red color and 2) Get the child element of the grid which is in the current cell. There does not seem to be any such event available on rowdefinition(s) or columndefinition(s) which would enable me to capture the current cell for (1). I was thinking on the lines that if I know the current cell, I should be able to get the correct child control of the grid  since all the cells contain same type of child.

Comment: I have changed my line of thinking and instead of having the windowsformhost control directly in the cell, I have created 4 child grids in each cell of the outer grid which contain the windowsformhost controls as children. Then I can get the correct object when the mousedown event is raised.